# How to save a matrix of complex entries in Octave / Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a FFT output as a matrix with complex numbers, and all the results I have found online about saving the matrix as a file to be used later on include some ad hoc loops, and discuss how the imaginary part is otherwise disregarded.

I wonder if there is an easier way.

As a toy example:

```
M = rand(3,3) + 1i * rand(3,3)

M =

 (0.159968,0.713216) (0.143438,0.379509) (0.636987,0.561565)
 (0.386119,0.723281) (0.720302,0.353988) (0.87171,0.445676)
 (0.536274,0.399646) (0.149597,0.574987) (0.358984,0.110503)
```

The answer in [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/11897-exporting-complex-data):

```
M = rand(3,3) + 1i * rand(3,3)

dlmwrite('M.txt', M)
```

fails to preserve columns and rows.

Comment: It depends entirely what you mean by "use later". If you're just going to load them back into MATLAB, why can't you just `save('test.mat', 'M')`?

Comment: @Wolfie Good point. I want to make the file as software-independent as possible. So I guess `.txt` is a good option. For instance, I want the file to display right away upon clicking on it from any computer.

Comment: @Wolfie Unfortunately my answer doesn't seem to preserve separations, columns or rows...

Comment: Save data in .txt file is a terrible idea. You lose precision, it is much slower and data is actually stored as text, as string, not as the number itself. Also, I believe there is no standard on how to save complex numbers in binary files, so you should decide on how to represent them. [This] answer on MATLAB Answers suggest to separate real and imaginary parts and save them on two different files. There is also a mex file to do it. If you really intend to save it as txt, you should be able to change the code accordingly

Comment: You really need to decide how you want to read the data. Being able to "display right away" is a pretty poor trade-off for precision issues, lack of compression, lack of standardization etc which you lose by not using a native file format. You could use other formats designed for numeric data (HDF5 / MAT / ...) and store the real and complex parts separately if you don't want to have complex MATLAB variables, but you need to clarify the objective.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this is the answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/11897-exporting-complex-data):

```
M = rand(3,3) + 1i * rand(3,3)

dlmwrite('M.txt', M)
```